# How to run my Code

Tags: java, swing

When I am running my code by making a HTML file in the browser, it is throwing a target invocation exception. In the command prompt using appletviewer `filename.java` command nothing is happening, using JDK 8.0.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class First extends JFrame {
   public void one() {
     JFrame obj = new JFrame();

     obj.setSize(200, 200);
     obj.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: its not an applet program. You are using swing. You are extending JFrame and inside that you are creating object of JFrame. Have look on tutorials first.

Comment: Whatever that is please tell me whether how can i run this piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not created an applet.  You have created a JFrame.

If you want to run an applet, then you need to extend from the Applet class.  For example:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

Learn more about applets:

- http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/papers/Java-tutorial/getStarted/applet/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

If you want to create a Java Swing application, not contained within an Applet, then you need to add a `main()` method.  For example:

```
public class First {

    public void one() {
        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        obj.setSize(200, 200);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First first = new First();  // instantiate your First object
        first.one();  // run your "one" method
    }
}
```

You can run this from the command-line like so:

```
javac First.java  <-- compiles it
java First  <-- runs it
```